# Cookies set in one tab of browser is not accessible in other tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, browser

I am working on an application where I am opening another tab with different application. I am setting a cookie "X" in first browser, When ever some activity happens on second tab I am updating this using response cookie(first delete and again create).

```
Response.Cookie.Add("X");
```

But when I try to access this cookie in the first tab, I am not getting the updated value from second tab. Is this not possible.

Comment: Are you opening the address link of same DOMAIN SERVER in both tabs? Because Cookie set from one domain can not be accessed from another.

Comment: Yes, we are setting the domain, but still the updated cookie value is not accessible from 1st tab.

Comment: No we can not set domain of a cookie programatically due to security reasons. What I am asking, are both of your applications that you are opening in diff tabs on same SERVER?

Comment: no they are not on same server, so if they are not on same server, will they not be accessible

Comment: No, for security reasons, browser doesn't let one domain to access another domain-cookie.

Comment: Okay, thank you, Can you post as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your applications are on different servers then for security reasons, browser doesn't let one domain to access another domain's cookie.

And we can not set domain of a cookie programatically due to security reasons again.